# JavaScript in Snowflake Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error for the code below

I am trying to load log table with below columns

SP_MASTER_VIEW_TO_TABLES_RS
V_QUOTE_VIEWNAMES_TO_BE_LOADED_TO_TABLE
these are the variables defined within SP

[image]

```
 var V_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS = `INSERT INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLENAME 
                             SELECT ` + SP_MASTER_VIEW_TO_TABLES_RS  + ` ,` + V_QUOTE_VIEWNAMES_TO_BE_LOADED_TO_TABLE + ` ,`  + `getdate(), ''EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY'';`
                                
                    var V_EXEC_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: V_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS} );
                    var V_RESULT_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS = V_EXEC_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS.execute();
                    V_RESULT_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS.next();
```

Error

```
Execution error in store procedure SP_MASTER_SP: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 72 unexpected '('. parse error line 28 at position 63 near '32'. parse error line 29 at position 138 near '44'. parse error line 52 at position 64 near '32'. parse error line 53 at position 138 near '44'. At Statement.execute, line 54 position 98
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to debug without seeing the real procedure. If you can't share the real procedure, please create a simplified version, run it and share the error belonging to the procedure.

I see that you directly add SP_MASTER_VIEW_TO_TABLES_RS and V_QUOTE_VIEWNAMES_TO_BE_LOADED_TO_TABLE variables to the SQL statement, so the value of them is important. Can't you share something like this?

```
create or replace procedure proc()
returns string
language javascript
as 
$$

SP_MASTER_VIEW_TO_TABLES_RS = 'abc';
V_QUOTE_VIEWNAMES_TO_BE_LOADED_TO_TABLE = 'xyz';

 var V_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS = `INSERT INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLENAME 
                             SELECT ` + SP_MASTER_VIEW_TO_TABLES_RS  + ` ,` + V_QUOTE_VIEWNAMES_TO_BE_LOADED_TO_TABLE + ` ,`  + `getdate(), 'EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY';`
                                
                    var V_EXEC_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: V_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS} );
                    var V_RESULT_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS = V_EXEC_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS.execute();
                    V_RESULT_INSERT_DIM_MASTER_SP_LOG_RS.next();
                    
$$;
```

Although all these details are missing, I noticed that this part has an error:

```
`getdate(), ''EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY'';`
```

You should not use double "single quotes", so it should be like this:

```
`getdate(), 'EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY';`
```

Comment: 'EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY' does not work, it throws error. Also two parameters , i used double quote SP_MASTER_VIEW_TO_TABLES_RS = ''abc'';
V_QUOTE_VIEWNAMES_TO_BE_LOADED_TO_TABLE = ''xyz'';

Comment: Can you share a minimal repro so we can provide a solution?